# Python list 'in' statement doesn't work correctly

Tags: python, list

I tried to used 'in' function to check some value available in a list or not. But it does not work correctly.

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

x ='what are bad'
a= word_tokenize(x)[0]
qestion = ['what,why,how,are,am,should']

if a in qestion:
 print 'question'
else:
 print 'not a question'
```

I couldn't find the reason for that. Can any one help me to solve this.

Comment: I don't think `['what,why,how,are,am,should']` does what you want: that's a list with only 1 element in it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following certainly is a list, but I don't think it's the list that you were looking for.

```
 qestion = ['what,why,how,are,am,should']
```

i think what you wanted was

```
question = 'what,why,how,are,am,should'.split(',')
```

which produces

```
['what', 'why', 'how', 'are', 'am', 'should']
```

Which is more likely to full fill your IF x in y condition.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I expected.

Comment: Glad to have been of help and all the best with your project.

Comment: Can you explain please why we should use .split(',') in this case.

Comment: Well the split function breaks up a strin into pieces. Since laziness is a virtue in programming using split here is easier than manually converting your original list to the required format :-)